# Why is Angular breaking my Google Fonts SCSS import?

Tags: angular, google-fonts

I've got this line on my global SCSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;400;700&family=Roboto&display=swap');
```

But for some reason, the URL gets somehow intercepted by Angular and the request being made by the browser is altered:
[image]

Obviously, Google Fonts ends up returning a 400 HTTP Status.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I guess we're running into this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20906
Recomendation is to use link in index as the answer below is already saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same trouble and finally I decided to desist of the import inside scss and added in index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while making the angular build. Adding below to the angular.json file worked for me.

"optimization": {
"scripts": true,
"styles": true,
"fonts": false
}